# The pycord operation is complete, but the discord outputs that the application is not responding

Tags: python, pycord

If you try to send a message at the end after doing something that takes a little time, it will be printed that you are not responding.
In this case, how can I wait for the bot to work?
Is that what ctx.defer() does?

The work is definitely done

Comment: Maybe you can use a Bot.wait_for() with timeout set to the certain time? https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Bot.wait_for

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest you to read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us help you. And sometimes doing that, we can even solve our problem without the need of others. If that occurs, feel free to answer your own question.